# c++ omp, compare parameter and constant

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments, constants, openmp

For example, I hava a function:

```
void function(int x, int y)
{
 code here;
}
```

and compared to that I use constant to replace the given x and y, it's much slower when I pass in parameters.

So how do I get as fast speed as I use constant even when I use variables x and y?

(there are mainly some core for-loops in the code)
I tried to #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(x, y) for every loop in the code, I got a speedup, but still not as fast as I use constants, any suggestions?
Or, is there any way that I can just treat the pass-in x and y as two constants?

Comment: If the values you pass in are const, then pass by const reference?

Comment: the values I pass in are two integers(int)

Answer (score 0):

I think by doing:

## pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(x, y)

You're essentially making the same for-loop run on each of your cores because the values are made private to each of the threads, so they're not really working together to get things done faster, and ends up being entirely counterproductive. Try using "shared" and adding in a synchronization clause, barrier in this case.

for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(x, y) 
    {
        #pragma omp barrier
        for(x = 0, y = 0; x <= 500000; x++, y++) {
            printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", x, y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

time that against this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(x, y) 
    {
        #pragma omp barrier
        for(x = 0, y = 0; x <= 500000; x++, y++) {
            printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", x, y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think I have your complete answer as I'm still playing around with it myself, but hopefully it helps in finding one.

the "OpenMP" article on wikipedia looks really good and I'm still in the process of reading it and making sense of it all...

Comment: @user2786737 no problem. also from the wiki: Currently only runs efficiently in shared-memory multiprocessor platforms (see however Intel's Cluster OpenMP and other distributed shared memory platforms). I've been trying to get better performance with OpenMP but it doesnt look like im gonna get it because I don't have multiple processors. Let me know if you get results though.